# pumping lemma for regular languages and DFA with k states

Tags: automata

The Formal statement of the pumping lemma for regular languages:

Let $L$ be a regular language. Then there exists an integer $p \ge 1$ depending only on $L$ such that every string $w$ in $L$ of length at least $p$ ($p$ is called the "pumping length") can be written as $w = xyz$ (i.e., $w$ can be divided into three substrings), satisfying the following conditions:

$|y| \ge 1$;

$|xy| \le p$

for all $i \ge 0$, $x(y^i)z$ $\epsilon L$

If $M$ is a DFA with $k$ states which implements $L$  (which means $L=L(M)$) , can I assume that  $p$(from the pumping lemma) is smaller or equal to $k$?

if so ,how to prove this assumption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You prove this by understanding why the pumping lemma works in the first place. For regular languages, the idea is simple.

First, observe that if you feed $n$ symbols to a DFA, it visits $n+1$ (not necessarily distinct) states - it starts out at the initial state, and each symbol changes the state at most once. You can view this sequence of $n+1$ states as a walk through the DFA's state graph.

Next, check what happens if a state is visited twice while accepting some word $w$, i.e. if the walk through the DFA's state graph contains a loop. Since the state is the *only* information the DFA has about the past, once it allows you to loop, it allows you to loop arbitrarily often. So what you do is you split $w$ into three parts $xyz$. $x$ leads you from the initial state to some state $q$ which is the starting point of the loop. $y$ leads you around the loop, i.e. starts and ends at state $q$. $z$ takes you from $q$ to some accepting state. Now, if you instead of $xyz$ feed the word $x\underbrace{y\ldots y}_{n\text{ times}}z$ to the DFA, the DFA won't know the difference - $x$ will still lead you to state $q$, then you walk the loop $n$ times, again ending up in state $q$, and finally go from $q$ to an accepting state.

This always works *if* the walk contains a loop. Now, if a DFA has $k$ states, *any* walk that visits more than $k$ states must visit some state at least twice, i.e. contain a loop. Since we concluded above that a word of lenght $n$ corresponds to a walk visiting $n+1$ states, if the word is at least $k$ symbols long, it'll at least visit $k+1 > k$ states. So yes, the pumping lemma applies to any word of $k$ symbols or more.